# comparing two array php array_diff

Tags: php, arrays, compare, diff

I got an empty array when I compare two arrays that have the different key but the same value. Example: id has the same value like yy

```
$o = array('id'=>2,'name'=>'D','yy'=>12); 
$n = array('id'=>12,'name'=>'D','yy'=>12);
```

What I want is :

```
$a = array('id'=>12,'id'=>2);
```

Comment: well you can get both `id` values on those array, you can't have the same keys in the same array though

Comment: This function array_diff() compares the values of multiple arrays, 
        and return an array that contains the entries from first array  
        that are not present in another array.
        
        so using this function you cannot get values from both arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`array_merge_recursive()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge-recursive.php) - `(PHP 4 >= 4.0.1, PHP 5, PHP 7)`

**From PHP Manual:**

**array_merge_recursive** — Merge two or more arrays recursively

```
<?php

$a = array('id'=>2,'name'=>'D','yy'=>12); 
$b = array('id'=>12,'name'=>'D','yy'=>12);

$result = array_merge_recursive($a, $b);

$newArr = $result['id']; // get ID index. you can also get other indexes.

echo "<pre>";
print_r($newArr);

?>
```

**Result:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2
    [1] => 12
)
```

**Note that:** you can not use same index name (**ID**) for this array `array('id'=>12,'id'=>2);`

Answer (score 0):

As @Ghost mentioned, an associative array should not have the same keys.
I suggest to achieve the "expected result" in "nested arrays" manner using `array_diff_assoc` function(c*omputes the difference of arrays with additional index check*):

```
$o = array('id'=>2,'name'=>'D','yy'=>12); 
$n = array('id'=>12,'name'=>'D','yy'=>12);

echo "<pre>";

$result_nested_arr = [array_diff_assoc($o, $n), array_diff_assoc($n, $o)];

var_dump($result_nested_arr);

// the output:
 array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(2)
  }
  [1]=>
  array(1) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(12)
  }
}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff-assoc.php